# JS Cлайдер для трекпада. Как определить когда 2 пальца были отпущены?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать слайдер для трекпада? Чтобы слайдер скролился двумя пальцами и при отпускании переходил на следующий слайд.

Скролл можно сделать через событие wheel. Он срабатывает только при движении, А как определить когда 2 пальца были отпущены?

```
function onScroll(e) {
    console.log(`x:${e.deltaX} y:${e.deltaY}`);
}

window.addEventListener("wheel", onScroll, false);
```

Пример работающего слайдера https://www.tesla.com/

Видео пример работы: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/nzWSXbFFD64

Comment: Ищите в MDN: `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend`, если вы именно про касания, то эти события должны вам помочь.

Comment: Трекпад не генериует евенты касаний, вместо этого он генерирует евенты мышки `wheel`, `mouseover`,  `mousemove`, `mouseout`.